# Calculate distribution of $Y$ random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, solution-verification, normal-distribution

I do not know if this exercise is correct. Let $X$ and $Z$ random variables independent with $P[Z=1]=P[Z=-1]=1/2$ and $X$ with standard normal distribution. If $Y=ZX$, determine the distribution of $Y$ and calculate $COV(X,Y)$.

My attemp

\begin{align*}
     P[Y\leq y]&=P[XZ\leq y, Z=1]+P[XZ\leq y, Z= -1]\\
     &=P[XZ\leq y| Z=1]P[Z=1]+P[XZ\leq y| Z= -1]P[Z= -1]\\
     &=P[X\leq y]\frac{1}{2}+P[-X\leq y]\frac{1}{2}\\
     &=1,
\end{align*}

and

$$E(XY)=E(XXZ)=E(X^{2}Z)=E(X^{2})E(Z).$$

Then I calculated $E(Z)$

$$E(Z)= (1)P(Z=1)+(-1)P(Z=-1)=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}=0$$

and

$$Cov(X,Y)=E(XY)-E(X)E(Y)=0-0=0.$$

Is it correct?

Comment: I think it should be intuitive that both $X$ and $-X$ have the normal distribution, which would make the resulting mixture have a normal distribution with probability 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution for $\mathbb{P}[Y \leq y]$ is nearly correct except for

$$ \mathbb{P}[X \leq y] \cdot \frac{1}{2} + \mathbb{P}[-X \leq y] \cdot \frac{1}{2} = 1 .$$

It should be intuitively clear that this is false, as it would imply $\lim_{y \to - \infty} \mathbb{P}[Y \leq y] = 1$ for example.

Instead, it should be

$$ \mathbb{P}[X \leq y] \cdot \frac{1}{2} + \mathbb{P}[-X \leq y] \cdot \frac{1}{2} = \mathbb{P}[X \leq y]  $$

as $\mathbb{P}[X \leq y] = \mathbb{P}[-X \leq y]$. This follows from $X$ being symmetric and continuous.

In particular, $Y$ is also a standard normal distribution.

For the covariance, your calculation is only correct if $X$ and $Z$ are independent.

It is fixable though using the law of total expectation:

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E} [XY] &= \mathbb{E} [X^2 Z] \\&= \mathbb{E} [X^2 Z | Z = -1] \cdot \mathbb{P }[Z=-1] + \mathbb{E} [X^2 Z | Z = 1] \cdot \mathbb{P }[Z=1] \\
&= \frac{1}{2}   \cdot \left(\mathbb{E} [-X^2] + \mathbb{E} [X^2]\right)\\ 
&= 0
\end{align*}

Comment: You are right, thanks!

Comment: I forgot to write down that $X$ and $Z$ are independent, but your approach is also valid.